# Given a line $l$, a line segment $d$, and a point $O$, construct a circle with center $O$ that cuts off a segment congruent to $d$ on the line $l$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, geometric-construction

I found this problem in Hawthorne's *Geometry: Euclid and Beyond* exercise $2.11$.

> Given a line $l$, a line segment $d$, and a point $O$, construct a circle with center $O$ that cuts off a segment congruent to $d$ on the line $l$.

[image]

I think it's possible to move $d$ onto $l$ such that it is perpendicularly bisected by a line from $O$, then the circle would cut the $d$ from the line. I'm curious if anyone knows an elegant solution to an interesting construction problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1- Mark A and B(A left and B at right) the ends of the segment d. Mark it's midpoint as D.Draw a circle center on A  and radius AB.

2- draw a line from A parallel with line l, it meets the circle at C.

3- A perpendicular from O on l intersect it at O'. O' is orthogonal projection of O on l.

4- Connect D to O'.

5- Draw two lines from A and C parallel with DO', they meet l at point N and M respectively.

Clearly $MN=AC=AB$. The circle center on O passing points points M and N is what you are looking for.

Update; I made a figure but I can not attach it due to problem I have with the site. I can send you if you give me an email address.

Comment: Could you attach some sort of visualization? I'm having trouble following the construction, especially with step $2$ & $3$.

Comment: Okay, could you send it to clke5351@colorado.edu? Thanks!